# Controlling Old Nokia phone via PC

Tags: usb, mobile-phones, nokia

I need to develop a PC program (C++ / C# ) in order to control basic actions (Calls and SMS) on an old Nokia phone (a one with black and white screen)

Do anyone knows where to find a library or a SDK for that purpose?

Edit:

Probably you can not download a program on that old phone..

The connection between the phone and PC will be on standard usb connector for that phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nokia distributes lots of Tools and SDK's which you can find [here](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Portal:Tools_and_SDK).

The usefulness depends on which type of Nokia you have, usually you can find type information beneath the battery.